# How to do server push with standalone Jetty

Tags: http, https, jetty, http2

I am trying to test the server push feature on a static website with standalone Jetty.

My website consists of an index.html Â+ 1 CSS + a bunch of images. The directory structure is:

```
/Album
Â Â Â Â|
Â Â Â Â|-----index.html
Â Â Â Â|-----style.css
Â Â Â Â|------/images
Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â|
Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â|-----image 1.png
Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â|---a set of 100 images
Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â|---image100.png
```

As I just wanted to quickly test out the server push feature I did not code this website as a Java Web project and, therefore, didn't have any web.xml file.

However, the Jetty documentation asks to add PushCacheFilter to web.xml. Therefore, I created a /Album/WEB-INF/web.xml in my project and added the PushCacheFilter as the documentation specified.Â

First, I am unable to understand from the documentation how exactly PushCacheFilter works.
Secondly, I want to control which files get pushed and which do not. From the documentation, it seems PushCacheFilter doesn't give me that kind of control.

I have checked a few examples on Internet but most of them are with embedded Jetty.
Will someone please help me to figure out how to test server push feature in my static website with standalone Jetty?

Also, I wanted to ask whether the HTTP/2 client example in Jetty's GitHub repository directly usable as such? Sorry, haven't tested the client myself. I just saw it in the repository and was curious. I'll be really thankful if someone can point me in the direction of example use casewith Jetty's HTTP and HTTP/2 client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too many questions and it's not really clear what you want to do :)

Jetty exposes a Jetty-specific API on the server to perform pushes (eventually, these APIs will be part of Servlet 4.0).

You can access this API using `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPushBuilder()`, see http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/PushBuilder.html

The `PushBuilder` APIs will then allow you to setup a resource to push, and to push it.

`PushCacheFilter` implements a cache of correlated resources.
When a primary resource that has correlated secondary resources is being requested, `PushCacheFilter` pushes those correlated resources using the `PushBuilder` APIs.

If `PushCacheFilter` does not fit your needs, you can write your own filter with your own logic and perform pushes using the `PushBuilder` APIs.

On the client side, if you want to use Java APIs to perform requests and receive pushes, you have to use `HTTP2Client`, see http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/client/HTTP2Client.html.

You can find examples of how to perform a request and receive pushes [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-http2/http2-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/client/PushCacheFilterTest.java).

If you want a full fledged example similar to yours (index.html + bunch of images), you can look at the [HTTP/2 demo](https://github.com/jetty-project/http2-demo).

UPDATE: Simple example of how to use `PushBuilder`.

```java
public class MyPushFilter implements Filter {
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        String uri = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        switch (uri) {
            case "/index.html":
                // Jetty specific APIs for now.
                PushBuilder pushBuilder = Request.getBaseRequest(request).getPushBuilder();
                pushBuilder.path("/styles.css").push();
                pushBuilder.path("/background.png").push();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
```

The example above is very very simple. It does not handle HTTP version, conditional headers, etc. Please have a look at the implementation of `PushCacheFilter` [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/PushCacheFilter.java) for a better implementation.

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I do agree that there were too many questions. At that time I just started with Jetty. I discussed this question in the mailing list as well.
What I am looking for now is to see a small example of how to use PushBuilder for a static website with standalone Jetty. Will you please give me some quick directions about it.

Comment: Jetty serves static files via its `DefaultServlet`, so in order to perform pushes you just need to add the `PushCacheFilter`. Look at the demo I pointed you at. I also edited the answer for a quick example of `PushBuilder`. Note that the API could change to reflect Servlet 4 developments.