# How Implement PushCacheFilter

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jetty-9, http2

org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushCacheFilter class in Java implements javax.servlet.Filter interface to identify resources to be pushed to a browser. The former class is provided by Jetty to implement HTTP/2 Push services for a client-server interaction.
How should we use the functionalities of this class in our Java based web projects? How do we deploy them ?
Specifically:- My server has a list of files which needs to be pushed onto a client. Which methods should I call to leverage the HTTP/2 Push ?
How do we deploy these classes into our web apps folder of jetty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty proposes an extension to the Servlet API (to be included in Servlet 4.0) that allows to push resources programmatically.

Jetty's `PushCacheFilter` just uses these APIs to push resources, and adds logic to dynamically track resources to push, so that it "learns" what to push.

If you have a different use case where you know beforehand what to push, and you don't need any of the logic performed by `PushCacheFilter`, then you can write your own Jetty `Handler` or Servlet filter that performs your logic.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162252/how-to-do-server-push-with-standalone-jetty)'s answer details the APIs to use.