# Spring Boot HTTP2 Server Push

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http2

Found the nice example from Brian Clozel about HTTP/2 and Spring Boot, especially with Server Push: https://github.com/bclozel/http2-experiments.
There is an `index.html` which has some image resources. However, those image are pushed to the server, but I have no idea where exactly this push is initiated from. I don't see any push filters or any other indicators which could lead to push the resources inside the `index.html`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are looking for this Config File:
https://github.com/bclozel/http2-experiments/blob/master/src/main/java/http2xp/WebConfig.java
There is a Jetty Push Filter configuration
http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/PushCacheFilter.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jetty's `PushCacheFilter` is configured [here](https://github.com/bclozel/http2-experiments/blob/master/src/main/java/http2xp/WebConfig.java) in the example.

`PushCacheFilter` will automatically "learn" what secondary resources are associated to any resource, and will automatically push them.

The example also shows a way to [programmatically push a resource](https://github.com/bclozel/http2-experiments/blob/master/src/main/java/http2xp/web/Http2Controller.java#L25).
However, that API has been deprecated in favor of using a [`PushBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162252/how-to-do-server-push-with-standalone-jetty).

`PushBuilder` will be part of Servlet 4.0, becoming a standard API.